# Safe alternative to mysql_real_escape_string? (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

I am passing a variable to a function that executes a query

The MySQL connection only occurs inside the function, and closes inside the function

I want to be able to safely escape strings BEFORE I send them to the function

I can't use mysql_real_escape_string because it requires a MySQL connection (which is only being made inside the function)

I know the simple answer would be to escape strings inside the function, but I cannot do this because I need to send some escaped, and some non-escaped parts of a string

For example, I need to run the function like this:

```
myquery("'" . escape_me("My string") . "'");
```

Notice I am sending two apostrophe's-- unescaped, with an escaped string inside.  For this reason I can't do a blanket mysql_real_escape_string on arguments inside of myquery function.

I found the following code, suggesting that I could use it as an alternative to mysql_real_escape_string:

```
// escape characters
function escape_me($value) {
    $return = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($value); ++$i) {
        $char = $value[$i];
        $ord = ord($char);
        if($char !== "'" && $char !== "\"" && $char !== '\\' && $ord >= 32 && $ord <= 126)
            $return .= $char;
        else
            $return .= '\\x' . dechex($ord);
    }
    return $return;
}
```

I do not know if this function is safe from multibyte attacks, but I think I also need to undo the function every time I query

For example, inputting:
Testing 3's "OK" is turned into Testing 3x27s x22OKx22 in the database

So my main question is:
Do you know if there is another function I can use as an alternative to mysql_real_escape_string that will safely escape characters?

Comment: got an example of unescaped stuff?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- It's terrible idea to connect every time you're calling this function. A good planned application wouldn't have such odd limitation.
- you can use substitutions, like this
  `myquery("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = %s","My string");`
- You can use another way of substitutions, a modern one: prepared statements. it will be described in numerous other answers.

as noone posted it yet, here is rough example

```
function fetchAll(){
 $args = func_get_args();
 $query = array_shift($args);
 $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
 $stmt->execute($args);
 return $stmt->fetchAll();
}
$a=$db->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM users WHERE status=? LIMIT ?,?",$status,$start,$num);
```

- As long as you're using single-byte encoding or utf-8, no need to use mysql_real_escape_string, so <s>mysql_escape_string</s>(deprecated) or addslashes would be enough

Comment: `mysql_escape_string` has been [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php) (in favor of `mysql_real_escape_string`), but other than that, good stuff. +1

Comment: That makes sense, connecting once for each pageload is better than connecting for each query - I can just do a db connect before the function runs, I was doing a connect inside thinking it was better to open and close connections for each query

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest passing in an array of values to be escaped and using `sprintf()` format the query while escaping each of the values. Here is the first part of my query function:

```
public function querya($query, $args=null){
    //check if args was passed in
    if($args !== null){
        //if an array...
        if(is_array($args)){
            //...escape each value in the args array
            foreach($args as $key=>$value){
                $args[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
            }
            //add the query to the beginning of the args array
            array_unshift($args, $query);
            //call sprintf with the array as arguments to sprintf
            $query = call_user_func_array("sprintf", $args);
        } else {
            //if args is not an array, then string (single argument passed in).
            $query = sprintf($query, mysql_real_escape_string($args));
        }
    }

    //perform query, other stuff
}
```

Comment: in the similar function I am adding quotes to %s wildcards, just as a foolproof, to be sure that no %s in the query left unquoted.

Comment: makes sense. This is used just by myself, so I usually write my queries like `$DB->querya("SELECT COLUMN FROM TABLE WHERE VALUE='%s' AND 1=%d",array('test',1));` and include the quotes around the %s inside the query when needed.